# Is debootstrap chroot safe?

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, chroot, hardening

I followed this tutorial http://wiki.debian.org/chroot on Debian Squeeze AMD64, to get a separated environment.

This chroot is really safe? In others chroot tutorials, create a chroot for an application is really hard, with this tutorial appears it install a small separated system in chroot, including a package manager.

My goal, is to make a chroot for nginx + php5-fpm, to hardening a linux server. Is that the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debootstrap is intended for package building and testing.
And I would not consider [chroot a security feature](http://securityblog.redhat.com/2013/03/27/is-chroot-a-security-feature/), to start with.

If your goal is to harden a server hosting a web server + web application, other measures are more appropriate, namely:

- dedicated separated partitions/LVs with restricted mount options:

For example, I have the DocumentRoot of my webserver set to `/srv/www`, which is a dedicated logical volume mounted whit restrictive options

`/dev/mapper/root_vg-srv_lv on /srv type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,quota,usrquota,grpquota,data=ordered,usrquota,grpquota)`

the relevant ones being `nodev, noexec, seclabel` and `*quota`.
All because developers can upload content via git hub/live repositories, and I choose not to trust them regarding safe permissions, ownership, SELinux labeling, etc...

- SELinux/AppArmor (the second possibly having better support in Debian as of now)

SELinux is, unfortunately, not fully functional in Debian (although squeeze is better supported than wheezy, IIRC). I suggest AppArmor for this reason. It should be easier to implement than SELinux.

- ModSecurity

You definitely want a web application firewall.

- IPTables + Fail2Ban

Combining these two tools can, at a very least, decrease the chances of an attack to succeed.

- Possibly quite a lot more depending on what your application is for.

Does you application use fill-in forms? does it manage a database? user authentication?
Securing a website is not an easy task, I'd suggest to read **[a lot](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)** before exposing anything *in the wild*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. Can you explain better or give me a link about the first point (separated partions/lvs with resticted mount options).

Selinux, appears to be so complicated, because it's impossible to look for a nginx's policy. Is Apparmor as safe as  selinux?

What do you mean for "quite a lot more"? For a webserver ngnix+ssl+php-fpm, what else would it do?

Thank you for the patience.

Comment: Thanks again. "Does you application use fill-in forms? does it manage a database? user authentication?" Yes, my application is a typical dynamic website, ecomerce, with forms, user login, database, all typical webserver service.

Yes, I know it's a really hard task, therefore I'm reading really much... But unlucky, the hardening tutorials are very generic and conflicting...

Comment: Do you have no more tips about? Thanks

Comment: Many, but that is not the way this site works: specific questions with specific answers. If you think my answer is valid, mark it so. If you think it's not valid, down-vote it. I think the question you made, as it stands, has been answered. I suggest starting by learning how to secure an OS, and then move onto securing a web server.

Comment: Yes, but from your final questions I supposed the answer could became more detailed. (My comments refers always to the same topic). Thank you.

Comment: that was meant to imply there are a lot of things about your application that I dont know so I cannot be more specific. I will try editing my answer to add some hints, but bear in mind it is a broad subject.